# Can not find assembly x ... when trying execute a C# Project (COM) in VC++

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have a problem to load assembly in project.

senario:

I have 4 assemblies A,B,C and D
assembly A is main project that uses B and C. On the other hand both of B and C have dependency to D.
In execution of project, first B tries to load D and it can. But when C wants to load and use D it gets a exception like this: can not find assembly D ...

In addition:

I Register A as a COM and call it in VC++ project.

any help?

Comment: Please include the full exact text of the error message.

Comment: Are you building in Visual Studio? Do you have the assembly set to Specific version in C? Are you coping to Local on either?

Comment: This is a pretty specific problem with using COM to use a [ComVisible] .NET assembly.  The CLR will only look in two places for dependent assemblies, the GAC first, then the directory that contains the EXE.  It will *not* look  in the directory that contains A.  That doesn't match your description, it should not find B either.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: thanks about your replies

Comment: thanks for your replies. I find source of my problem but i cant resolve that. I have serialization and deserialization in assembly D both methods in one class. when my project uses serialization method, it has no problem but when it uses deserialization method it gets exception. any idea? is it possible in first invoke, my project uses a loaded assembly of D and in second one, it uses from another loaded assembly?

Comment: I find source of my problem but i cant resolve that.I have serialization and deserialization in assembly D both methods in one class. when my project uses serialization method, it has no problem but when it uses deserialization method it gets exception. any idea? is it possible in first invoke, my project uses a loaded assembly of D and in second one, it uses from another loaded assembly?